# Refer to match big looping data

Tags: regex

I have one regex which works fine for upto 1000 records. But when it comes more than that it shows stack overflow error. I'm using this regex in java code. (eclipse)

Here is my regex:

```
X00(X01((P00){1}(T00){1,99}){1,9999}H00)V99
```

The data is going to come in single line record with specific number of occurrences.

Here is an example of data

```
X00X01P00T00T00T00P00T00T00T00T00T00H00V99
```

Max limit of specific word is mentioned in regex and of whole group occurrence as well (1, 9999}. And within in one group P00 is going to be occur one time and T00 is upto 99 times and this group itself can be repeated itself can be repeated upto 9999 times. I hope its clear now..

What can be done in this regex to match long data coming into this pattern mentioned in above regex... upto 10000 records?

Comment: Using atomic grouping here might help avoiding unnecessary backtracking in instances where the regex doesn't match.

Comment: Is the whole record supposed to have this pattern, or can the record contain text before/after the match that has nothing to do with the pattern? If not the whole record: can there be multiple matches in one record?

Comment: @trincot, As you can see all words are of three characters in my input data. And one word is itself is one record. And combination of all words is one input data set. Which needs to be matched with my regex mentioned in question. In my data, records are occurring in group wise and whole group can be repeated multiple time. ..except the first(X00, X01) and last two(H00, V99) record..

Comment: In that case you'll have a major improvement if you add the end-of-string anchors in your regex: `^` at the start, `$` at the end, and then use the `m` modifier.

Comment: BTW, you never need to use `{1}` in a regexp. Any pattern without a quantifier will match exactly once.

Comment: @Barmar, Any suggestion how can I add atomic group to my regex ? so that it could work for long input data. How can I set up this ?> in my regex to make it more powerful ? check this demo https://www.regex101.com/delete/Xf8EkYmIka1PwzoWiZLvBnns

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but `(P00)` is an atomic group all by itself. You don't need to put `{1}` after it.

Comment: @Barmar check this demo https://www.regex101.com/r/JJBxfM/1

Comment: regex101 cannot handle that expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want a record to match the pattern as a whole, you should add the start-of-string (`^`) and end-of-string (`$`) anchors in your regular expression. This way you avoid that matching attempts are made at other positions in a line, which you would not want to match that way anyway.

Depending on whether you parse all records in one go, you may need to specify the multiline modifier: `m`.

Secondly, the large number in `{1,9999}` may cause difficulty for some regex parsers. There is not much you can do about that, if indeed that poses a problem, as it has to do with the size of the compiled regular expression. In that case you could try with a negative look-ahead to see you don't have more than 9999 occurrences, and when that passes, then just do a `+` (i.e. "one or more"), but it suffers from the same problem on reg101.com (too large expression):

```
^X00((?!(?:.*?P){10000})X01((P00)(?!(?:T00){100})(T00)+)+H00)V99$
```

If the numbers 99 and 9999 were not really strict limits, then you could take out those negative look-aheads ( `(?! .... )` ): that would really be a time-saver.

### Explanation of the `(?! ... )`

The meaning of `(?!(?:.*?P){10000})`

- `(?!`: start a negative look-ahead: this does not "eat" any characters, but looks ahead.
- `(?:`: start of a non-capturing group. Similar to normal parentheses, but you cannot back-reference them.
- `.*?P`: any characters up to a "P".
- `{10000}`: count that many occurrences, which practically means: see if you can find 10000 "P" in the string: if so, the look-ahead succeeds, but since it is a negative look-ahead, the match will fail, which is the purpose.

Comment: @trincot...its working..thanks for your time. But could you please explain me what's happening here (?!(?:.*?P){10000}) and (?!(?:T00){100} ?..I'm curious to know :) would be much appreciated if you could explain with symbol explanation..for learning purpose.

Comment: I added an explanation of the first of the two in my answer. I think you will then also understand the second one.